# Display button and ul in a column and centered

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am building a responsive nav-bar using React.js which needs to "collapse" into button and ul displayed in column in the center. The button is currently perfectly centered but the ul is a little off. I am pulling my hair out trying to solve this. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried all the flexbox tricks but nothing is working.

```
App.css

li {
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-top:1em;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.navBar {
    width:100%;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.links {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.show-nav {
    height: 100%;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

      button {
        display: none;
      }
      .links {
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        font-size: 0.8em;
      }
      .navBar {
        width:100%;
        background-color:gray;
        color: white;
        padding: 0.5em;
      }
      li {
        padding: 0 1em;
      }
}
```

App.js:

```
<div className="navBar">
            <button onClick = {this.Toggle}>
              <FiMenu/>
            </button>
            <ul className = {this.state.toggle ? "links show-nav" : "links"}>
           {
             li.map((objLink, i) => {
                  return ( <li key={i}><a href={objLink.link}>{objLink.text}</a></li> )
                  })
           }
            </ul>
</div>
```

When the button is toggled I want all items (the button and the lis) to be displayed in a column in the center on the same axis.

Comment: What are their heights, they probably have different heights.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the paddings and margins of the ul?

Comment: Can you clarify this? You mean that the button should be the same height as list items? I want them stack one on the top of the other in a column in the center of the page. Does the height of an element affect this?

Comment: @MrLister OMG! Thank you! I have just reset both paddings and margins and everything is perfectly aligned. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the ul margin and padding settings. I have added this to my App.css:

```
ul {
    padding: 0em;
    margin: 0em;
}
```

All is perfectly aligned now.

Comment: Thank you @MrLister